# Is there a way to prompt the user with a password to stop lock task mode?

Tags: kotlin

I want to use lock task mode to lock a device to use a single app but have the ability for a user to input a password to exit lock task mode. I would prefer to use an item from the toolbar to stop lock task mode. These devices are essentially a kiosk that service providers will use to access information. They will be distributed around the country with no internet access so I need a way for a remote user to take them out of lock task mode to trouble shoot. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: sounds like a feature that would be OS dependend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I created an alertdialog with a password input that takes it out of lock task mode.

```
    private fun showAlertWithTwoButton() {
            val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
            alertDialog.setTitle(Constant.ALERTTITLE)
            val input = EditText(this)
            input.hint = "Enter Password"
            input.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
            input.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or 
            `enter code here`InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD

        alertDialog.setView(input)
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, Constant.ACCEPT) { 
        dialogInterface, i ->
            val password = input.text.toString()
            if (password == "your password") {
                // Do something here when clicking accept button

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, Constant.REJECT) { 
        dialogInterface, i ->
               // Do something here when clicking reject button
            }

        alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {
              // Do something here when clicking outside of alertdialog
        })

        alertDialog.show()
        }
```